# Possible bug in ZipArchive with archive mode update?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I ran into a problem with `ZipArchiveMode.Update` if the zip file contains "directory entries".

I know there is no such thing as directory entry but some tools produce entries with `ZipArchiveEntry.Length = 0` and `ZipArchiveEntry.Name = ""` for directories in the zip file.

The following code now corrupts the zip file:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(@"D:\TEMP\test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
}
```

As you can see I do nothing at all except for opening the zip file with `ZipArchiveMode.Update` and dispose it in the end.

The problem is that the "directory entries" seem to be treated as file entries. So in the output there are new zero byte entries with the directory names.

I still can open the zip file and even extract files per drag&drop. But attempts to extract the zip file result in error messages. Maybe because there are two entries with the same fullname?

My workaround was to avoid `ZipArchiveMode.Update` and use a temporary `MemoryStream`. Then iterate over all entries, ignore "directory entries" and only copy the file entries to the stream. This way it worked.

Is this a bug in `ZipArchive` or are entries for directories just wrong? What if I want to store empty directories in the zip? And as I said: Many tools out there seem to produce such directory entries.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when trying to update a zip file with directory entries, after updating the file the zip file exist (with the new added file) but its corrupted.

What worked for me eventually was adding Nuget reference to `DotNetZip` and add the file using `Ionic.Zip`:

```
using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(parameters.ObjzfPath)) 
{
    zip.AddEntry("newFileEntry", "newFileContent"); // you can use zip.AddFile("newFile.txt") as well
    zip.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell script I had an issue with the Compress-Archive with update mode and also with System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\OtherStuff\*.txt -Update -DestinationPath archive.zip

# set an alias for 7zip
set-alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zip =  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($zipfileName,"Update")
$zip.Dispose()
```

As soon as I openned the zip in update mode it would immediatly get corrupt. My solution was to use 7zip.

```
# unzip to temp folder from ziplocation
sz x -o"$tempFolder" $zip_location -r ;

#edit file as wished

# remove the original zip
rm -fo $zip_location
# zip the folder with /* wilcard at the end to select only the contents     
sz a -tzip "$zip_location" "$tempFolderWild"
# remove the temp folder
rm -fo -r $tempFolder
```